# Как из содержимого тега (в котором есть буквы и цифры) получить цифры?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Как из содержимого тега (в котором есть буквы и цифры) получить цифры с помощью регулярных выражений?

Из `23424<test>my1234</test>35345` нужно получить `1234`.

Comment: Пишите вопрос корректнее. В последней строчке утверждение `Из ...` не соответствует вашей задаче. В текущей формулировке регулярка `\d+` решает задачу.

Comment: Не решает. Смотрите ответы ниже.

Comment: В обновлённой формулировке - `/<test>.*(\d+).*<\/test>/`

Comment: Спасибо. Но я так делал, думал можно проще.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть очень удобный сервис для таких вещей: https://regex101.com/
А регулярное выражение будет такое:

```
[0-9]+

>>> a = "<test>my1234</test>"
>>> re.findall('[0-9]+', a)
['1234']
```

На PHP будет так:

```
$a = "<test>my1234</test>";
preg_match("/[0-9]+/", $a, $output_array);
print_r($output_array);
```

Удобный сайт, который генерирует регулярные выражения для PHP: http://www.phpliveregex.com/

Comment: на сайте работает, а  меня почему-то нет, в чём может быть проблема? http://prntscr.com/eafhm2

Comment: На сайте по умолчанию установлен флаг /g(global),  возможно, дело в этом.

Comment: неа, всё равно не работает

Comment: Исправил свой ответ, там есть рабочий пример на PHP.

Comment: `$a = "345345<test>my1234</test>235423";` эта регулярка берёт только первые цифры (а мне нужно из тега вынуть)

Comment: Можно сначала получить из строки теги, а затем к ним применить другую регулярку. Если тегов несколько, обернуть в цикл: $input_line = "345345<test>my1234</test>235423";
preg_match("/<[^>]*>(.*?)<[^>]*>/", $input_line, $tag);
preg_match("/[0-9]+/", $tag[0], $output_array);
print_r($output_array);

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", '', $str);
```

вроде так

Comment: В интернете видел данный пример. Но мне нужно именно вытащить цифры, а не убрать всё кроме них, потому что у меня огромная строка, в которой куча цифр, поэтому мне нужно вытащить их из содержимого определенного тега.

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = "<test>my1234</test>qwerty<test>my4321</test>";

preg_match_all('#<\s*?test\b[^>]*>(.*?)</test\b[^>]*>#s', $str, $matches);
$num_str = implode(',',$matches[0]);

preg_match_all('!\d+!', $num_str, $match);
$fin_str = implode(',',$match);

print_r($fin_str);
```

Comment: Мне нужно из содержимого тега вытащить только цифры.

Comment: это решение и вытаскивает вам из тега (тут переменная) массив, в котором будут только цифры. об_implode_айте его, и получите строку.

Comment: Но мне нужно именно вытащить цифры, а не убрать всё кроме них, потому что у меня огромная строка, в которой куча цифр, поэтому мне нужно вытащить их из содержимого определенного тега.

Comment: Вы немного меня сконфузили. Вам на выход надо получить строку без циферок, или циферки без строки?

Comment: Циферки без строки из содержимого определенного тега, но как я сказал в комментариях к ответам выше, у меня огромная строка, и перед тегом, с которого мне нужно получить цифры, может попасть много цифер.

Comment: посмотрите ответ, я вас правильно понял?